# Cbind get environment objects in R

Tags: r, environment-variables

I would like cbind the vectors of same dimension using a vector of their names.

For example I would like get from

```
a <- c(2, 5, NA, NA, 6, NA)
b <- c(NA, 1, 3, 4, NA, 8)
```

A matrix using `cbind(a,b)`

```
      a  b
[1,]  2 NA
[2,]  5  1
[3,] NA  3
[4,] NA  4
[5,]  6 NA
[6,] NA  8
```

but calling variables from a vector of environment objects names, e.g. `vectornames <- c("a","b")`

My last try failed on `cbind(for(i in vectornames) get(i))`

Answer (score 2):

You want to `sapply`/`lapply` the `get` function here. For example:

```r
a <- c(2, 5, NA, NA, 6, NA)
b <- c(NA, 1, 3, 4, NA, 8)
nmes <- c("a", "b")

# Apply get() to each name in the nmes vector
# Then convert the resulting matrix to a data frame
as.data.frame(sapply(nms, get))
```

```
   a  b
1  2 NA
2  5  1
3 NA  3
4 NA  4
5  6 NA
6 NA  8
```

Technically you can do this using `cbind`, but it's more awkward:

```r
# Convert the vector of names to a list of vectors
# Then bind those vectors together as columns
do.call(cbind, lapply(nms, get))
```

Comment: Thank you!. I'm not very friendly with "lapply, sapply, apply, mapply" family. It helps me very much.

Comment: There is also `mget` ; `do.call(cbind, mget(nmes))` ... and it shows a bit clearer that it would be better to try and keep the objects (`a`, `b` etc) in a list rather than just floating about the global env.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `mget` to 'get' a list, then `"loop-unlist"` with `sapply` and `function(x) x` or `[` to create a matrix

```
sapply(mget(vectornames), \(x) x)

#OR

sapply(mget(vectornames), `[`)

      a  b
[1,]  2 NA
[2,]  5  1
[3,] NA  3
[4,] NA  4
[5,]  6 NA
[6,] NA  8
```